# Batch adding leading zeros to the variable

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to create leading zeros generator, based on count of symbols in variable, that adds some zeroes before variable's value with length limitation.

I wrote code, but I'm stuck with next problem: my code stops working after first value (0 that turns to 00000), but it must process up to value 10 (end number must be 00010).

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set num_max=10
set num_len=5

for /l %%i in (0,1,%num_max%) do (
    set num=%%i
    :loop
        set "len=0123456789!num!"
        set "len=!len:~-10,1!"
        if not !len! equ %num_len% (
            set num=0!num!
            goto loop )
        echo !num! is !len! symbols long
)
pause
```

What is wrong with it? Please, help.

P.S. Sorry for my poor English.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

May I suggest a different, simpler approach?

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set num_max=10
set num_len=5

set "base=1"
for /L %%i in (1,1,%num_len%) do set "base=!base!0"

for /L %%i in (0,1,%num_max%) do (
   set /A "num=base+%%i"
   echo !num:~1!
)
```

Output:

```
00000
00001
00002
00003
00004
00005
00006
00007
00008
00009
00010
```

Comment: Thank you, this is that thing, that I've searched for!

Comment: Update for the interest: why this script begins to print-out wrong numbers, if 'num_len' is greater or equal to 10?

Comment: Because after 9 digits the maximum 32-bits integer number `2147483647` overflows in the `set /A` command...

Comment: Much thanks! I thought so, but I was don't know the max size of integer (there are a lot of them) for this command. :)

Answer (score 1):

You are not allowed to have a label (:loop) within a `code block` (parenthesised set of commands).

Try

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set num_max=10
set my_num=123

set "my_num=0000000000%my_num%"
set "mynum=!my_num:~-%num_max%!"
echo %my_num%
```

Or, if you want to build the leading zeroes,

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set num_max=10
set my_num=123
:loop
set "my_num=0%my_num%"
if "!mynum:~%num_max%!" equ "" goto loop
echo %my_num%
```

Both of which should be easy enough to read.